# How to save a PDF opened in IE new browser

Tags: selenium, user-interface, automation

I have a scenario to save a PDF which is opened in a window. By default selenium control moves to the Window, As it is a banking application I cannot repost the URL to save the pdf, I cannot press CTRL + S and right click doesn’t have any required data but using Robot I can click or move to an element, now the save button will enable only if you mouse over at the bottom of the page. I tried using ROBOT mouse over but the pop up did not popped up may be the reason it is not navigating via UI.
I have tried Sikuli also as the save pop up only pop up while mouse over that also failed.

We cannot use Actions as it wont support Webdriver driver, I have used Sikuli and ROBOT class mouse over.
The save Pop up opens only when it is mouse over at the bottom of the page, and it is not happening in ROBOT class as it navigates via DOM. please help

Comment: What are you expecting? do you need to download the pdf?

Comment: Yes I have to download and then verify few fields in the PDF, then I have to upload that.